# iPhone 4S CDMA updating and activating

Tags: iphone, cdma

I live in Iran and I want to buy a CDMA iPhone 4S.I know that I won't be able to use CDMA network and I have no problem with that.Basically I want to have an iPhone but use it as an iPod because I can only afford the money of a CDMA iPhone.GSM models are much more expensive and I have two other cell phone so I have no problem with not having a network in my iPhone.

Now, I have few questions:

If a CDMA iPhone is updated but not in range of the CDMA network,will it be deactivated ? I mean when I update a running and usable CDMA iPhone 4S which has no network,will it become deactivated after the update ? If it becomes deactivated,is there any way to make it activated and usable without being in the CDMA network range ?

I searched for iOS 8 update for iPhone 4S CDMA but I only found "Iphone 4S" title, not iPhone 4s CDMA, check this link : http://www.iphonehacks.com/download-iphone-ios-firmware

All other GSM and CDMA iPhones and iPads have their own dedicated update but there is only iPhone 4S title,no GSM,and no CDMA.

Does this mean that for iPhone 4S there is only one update that works on both GSM and CDMA versions ?

Comment: I can't answer this question, but I would seriously advise against getting a CDMA iPhone when an iPod Touch can be bought for very little brand new.

Answer (score 1):

Every iPhone requires a network ID (whether this is a SIM card or eePROM chip or whatever is irrelevant). Essentially, so long as the phone thinks there is a possibility of it getting a network connection, you're fine.